# jQuery .first() method returns a collection intead of the first element

Tags: jquery, methods, undefined-behavior

Using the first() method on a collection of elements displays wierd behavior.

```
$("button.overlay").on("click",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    let i = $(e.target).closest('.style-display').children('.modal-info-container');
    let k = i[0];
    let j = i.first();
});
```

To my understanding using [0] and .first() should give the same result. What happens is that .first() returns the unchanged collection instead.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> using [0] and .first() should give the same result

No.  This is not correct.

`$(selector).first()` is the same as `$(selector).eq(0)`

Both of these (.first/.eq) return a jquery collection.

while

`$(selector)[0]` is the same as `$(selector).get(0)` - See [get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/) - which retrieves the DOM node instead of returning a jquery collection.

---

`.first()` will return the *"unchanged collection"* if the original collection had only 1 element.

Consider `$("div").length` vs `$("div").first().length`

Comment: Thanks. API docs say ".first() method constructs a new jQuery object from the first element in that set.". This got me confused.

Comment: Yes, `.first()` is also the same as `$($(selector)[0])`, which matches the description of "a new jQuery object from the first element".  A "jquery object" is also referred to as a "jquery collection".